# What's the difference between a Kubernetes Admission Controller (Plugin) and an Admission Webhook?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

Admission Controllers (Plugins) and Admission Webhooks look very similar on the surface. What is the actual, functional difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admission Controllers are conflated to mean both Admission Plugins and Admission Webhooks by experts and even the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/21/a-guide-to-kubernetes-admission-controllers/).
I will call them Admission Plugins and Admission Webhooks to prevent confusion.

Admission Plugins are **not an API resource**. They can't be created by cluster administrators. They are [hardcoded into the Kubernetes source code.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/ea0764452222146c47ec826977f49d7001b0ea8c/pkg/kubeapiserver/options/plugins.go#L105-L139)

Specifically, Admission Plugins are a tool with limitless power. Since they are baked into `kube-apiserver`, they have the ability to [simply request for resources without authentication.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/ea0764452222146c47ec826977f49d7001b0ea8c/plugin/pkg/admission/storage/storageclass/setdefault/admission.go#L69-L73) They use this power to implement the `DefaultStorageClass` Admission Plugin, which checks all of the `StorageClass`es to find one with a default annotation applied to it.

Admission Webhooks on the other hand, are actually [an implementation of an Admission Plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#validatingadmissionwebhook), with the extra power removed. Note how a `Webhook.Validator` [does not have the ability to access any resources](https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/webhook/admission#Validator) besides the exact object being validated at the time.
Admission Webhooks [**are API resources**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#validatingwebhookconfiguration-v1beta1-admissionregistration-k8s-io), and are usually the first thing recommended when implementing a validator for a Kubernetes Operator, or a CRD in general. Despite this,  [signed certificates are required](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/issues/4179#issuecomment-761105450), which can make you abandon the whole idea.

### What does this mean for the average developer?

To write a validator that relies on checking existing objects in the cluster, you need to go through extra steps by using the [Kubernetes Golang Client API](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go), which relies on having a service account token with the correct RBAC applied.

You can also [update your object with a Status instead](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1#Status), explaining the reason validation failed. If you are writing a Kubernetes Operator, that can be written in the reconciliation loop.

If you have written a fancy UI for your custom resource, you should be able to read these statuses and expose them to the user in a nicer way. Unfortunately, OpenShift 4.X users are not able to add fancy UIs to the OpenShift Web Console, and will have to settle for exposing `Route`s.